# MVC Query should return results from ajax partial view or as PDF document based on form option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that allows visiting users to query a database and return information based on zipcode.  I need to provide two options, one for showing the information embedded in the page and another option for alternately returning the information as a pdf document.

My current solution is to have one ajax form that returns a PartialViewResult and the other form returns a FileContentResult.

This works; however, it would be cleaner to have a single form with a `dropdown` indicating whether to show the information embedded in the page or generated as a pdf document.  This is how I had it coded when the page was an `aspx` page, but I have been unable to figure out how to do that using `mvc`.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you stuck on how to create a page which does two different actions depending on the radio button, or stuck on how to create a controller method that returns either a `PartialViewResult` or a `FileContentResult` ?

Comment: How to do two different actions depending on a radio button.  I'm actually using a dropdown list but it would be the same thing.

Comment: Also note, the data is constantly changing so the pdf document is being dynamically created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after giving this some thought I was able to come up with a solution.  Here's what I did.  I got rid of the form for displaying the information to a file and kept the form for making the ajax call returning the desired results embedded in the page.  This allows me to show the progress indicator (spinning icon with working... text) while looking up the information and display success or failure messages.  I then created a partial view called tofile.cshtml.  To the ajax call I added an onSuccess definition.  The form definition now looks like this:

```
<pre>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("tobrowser", new AjaxOptions {
      HttpMethod = "GET",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      UpdateTargetId = "zipLookupResults",
      OnBegin = "showProgress",
      OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
      OnComplete = "onComplete"
}))
{

    ....
}
</pre>
```

Inside the controller I check to see if the user has selected to display the information inside the browser or to save it to file.  If they have choosen to save it to file then I save the form values into session variables and return the partial view, specifying to use the tofile view.

```
<pre>
  if (model.ResultDestination.ToLower().Contains("file"))
  {
      Session["ZipCode"] = model.ZipCode;
      Session["ResultDestination"] = model.ResultDestination;
      Session["SortBy"] = model.SortBy;

      return PartialView("tofile", model);
  }
</pre>
```

The tofile view simply defines a hidden input field with an id/name of "tofile".

Then I defined some javascript to handle the onSuccess of the ajax form.  I look for an element with an id of "tofile".  If that object is found then I redirect to the tofile method inside my controller.  I save my previously saved session values back into the model, lookup the information, format it and return it using the FileContentResult object.

```
<pre>
public FileContentResult tofile(ZipLookupModel model)
{
    model.SortBy = Session["SortBy"].ToString();
    model.ResultDestination = Session["ResultDestination"].ToString();
    model.ZipCode = Session["ZipCode"].ToString();

    model.WebResponse = WebService.ZipLookup(model.ZipCode, model.SortBy);

    if (model.ResultDestination.Contains("CSVFile"))
    {
        return new FileContentResult(writeHamsToCSV(model).ToArray(), "text/csv");
    }
    else
    {
        return new FileContentResult(writeHamsToExcel(model).ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }
}
</pre>
```

Works like a charm!  Now on to adding additional formats.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to handle this client side and leave your back end alone.  When the selection is made to get a pdf (either immediately or on form submit), select the url that returns the pdf and don't fire it as ajax.  When the form is submitted otherwise, just fire the ajax.

Assuming you're using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
<form class="my-form" action="/some-default">
    <!-- all your form stuff -->
</form>
<select class="my-select">
    <option value="/some-ajax-route" selected>Fire ajax on submit</option>
    <option value="/some-pdf-route">Get pdf on submit</option>
</select>

$(".my-select").on("change", function(event) {
    var selectListValue = $(this).val();
    $(".my-form").attr("action", selectListValue);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code for doing this?  When the user clicks on the submit button, how would I then not fire the ajax and post the field data to the url that returns the pdf?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This looked promising but has the same issues I have been struggling with.  If I set it up as an ajax call then the pdf gets imbedded in the page instead of being seen as a pdf that can be downloaded or saved.  If I set it up as a normal form then the pdf works correctly but the html is displayed as its own page instead of being imbedded in the master page.  Is there something obvious that I am just missing on this?  Thanks again.

Comment: Please take a screenshot of what's happening and then make a second image of what you want to have happen and we'll figure it out for you.

Comment: Here is a link to the page in question: <http://www.radioqth.net/ziplookup>.  I want the same functionality but with a combined single form and one of the options in the "Download results to" dropdown would be to display the information on the page as the "Display in Browser" form does.  So the information is either embedded on the page inside the master or a dialog pops up asking if the user wants to save or open the data.